# Problem with sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr conversion to IplImage

Tags: c++, sensor-msgs, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Ros-Users,

i have a strange problem using the CvBridge and OpenCV. I subscribed to a topic delivering images. The Problem is that cvSaveImage() fails sometimes with :

**OpenCV Error:** `Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 641 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv-1.4.1/debian/ros-diamondback-vision-opencv/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/vision_opencv/opencv2/build/opencv-svn/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:641: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat`

The strangeness is that if i do cvSaveImage() directly in my callbackFunction it does not fail at all. Ist just fails (after some time) if i push the images back into a vector. I want to buffer the images for later processing and then store them to HDD, so that's why i am doing the vector-stuff.

My callback function is:

```
void RosClass::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg){
       //image_queue is a std::vector<sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr>
       //cvSaveImage("test.jpg", getIplImage(msg)) works perfectly
       image_queue.push_back(temp);
}
```

My Function to convert the Ros-Image to an IplImage is:

```
IplImage* RosClass::getIplImage(sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr msg){  

    IplImage *img = 0;
    std::string cv_encoding="passthrough";
    sensor_msgs::CvBridge bridge;

    try{
        img = bridge.imgMsgToCv(msg, cv_encoding);
    }catch(sensor_msgs::CvBridgeException error) { //TODO: Compiler meldet ein Warning
        ROS_ERROR("Failed to convert sensor_msgs::Image to img_t with error [%d]", error);
        return 0;
    }

    return img;
}
```

This is the function where i retrieve the images from the vector and try to save them to HDD. But this fails. Not instantly but after some time. My workflow is only: Push images to the vector - if vector.size() > Threash - store them to HDD - clear the vector. Thats all. It seems like the cvSaveImage() fails after the vector was 1 time cleared. I have no idea whats the problem. Any suggestions? :)

```
void RosClass::processBufferedImages(){
    for(int i = 0; i < image_queue.size();i++){
        //Convert to IplImage -> works without any problems
        IplImage *img = getIplImage(image_queue.at(i));
        //Save Images to HDD -> fails after some time ... :/
        cvSaveImage("test.jpg",img);
    }
    image_queue.clear()
}
```

Thx for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9286/problem-with-sensor_msgs::image::constptr-conversion-to-iplimage/) by [Handsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/236/handsan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-03-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Handsan](https://answers.ros.org/users/236/handsan/) on 2011-03-04**:
Update: If i uncomment the "image_queue.clear()" it fails anyway. Not instantly but after a short time. The vector size is low with an element count of lower than 100 elements. So the amount of memory should not be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem, to solve it, I made a local copy of the image received each time and that was the image that I stored on an array.

---

Originally posted by [Javier](https://answers.ros.org/users/277/javier/) with karma: 408 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-03-11**:
As far as I understand the ConstPtr typedef magic, it is a reference-counting pointer-class. However as it is given by reference, not by value, there is no new instance created and thus the reference counter isn't increased. So I imagine it should suffice to copy (or receive by value) the ConstPtr. Just a guess though

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
void RosClass::imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::Image::ConstPtr& msg){
       image_queue.push_back(temp);
}
```

What is this "temp" you are pushing?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-03-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1